# Javascript function not working as expected in IE

Tags: javascript

This code below works fine in chrome, Firefox and Edge.  But when I try this same code in html I get the following error.

> SCRIPT5009: 'ddlTest' is undefined

```
<select id="ddlTest">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<script>

    function testFunc() {
        var y = (ddlTest).value;
        alert(y);
    }

</script>
```

Is there a way I can get around this in IE , other than doing :

> document.getElementById('ddlTest').value

Comment: document.getElementById('ddlTest').value is recommended

Comment: thanks. I actually tried that and it works .. but i am just wondering why it works on all browsers except for IE... is this a bug in IE or just not the right way to do it?

Comment: (ddlTest) is not the right way,,,,you can do this on other browsers maybe just because the browsers want to give you more convenince. i didn't see the kind of use in any documents.  document.getElementById  is the official API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature to have a property on `window` to access an element by ID was added in HTML5.

> The HTML5 standard [specifies](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object) that the `window` object must have a property *key* whose value is *elem* if...
>
> - there is exactly one DOM element *elem* whose property `id` has the value *key*.
> - there is exactly one  DOM element *elem* whose property `name` has the value *key*. *elem*’s tag must be one of: a, applet, area, embed, form, frame, frameset, iframe, img, object.

~ http://2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html

**However, you should *not* use this in your actual code -- use `document.getElementById('elem')` instead:**

> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`.

~ https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: in the first link you show,id couldn't get the element if the tag is select.though,still vote up for you.

Comment: @xianshenglu I don't understand? `select` isn't in the list for properties with a *name*, but in the example, it has an *id*, which works for every element type.

Comment: sorry , i am  just blind

Comment: @xianshenglu no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to do it is to get the element through the document:

```
function testFunc() {
    var ddlTest = document.getElementById('ddlTest');
    var y = ddlTest && ddlTest.value;
    alert(y);
}
```

Comment: yes it actually works fine in chrome, firefox and edge (those are the three i tested so far)... but IE it breaks...

Comment: any idea why it breaks in IE?  is it an incorrect way to do it..? just for learning purpose...

Comment: @psj01 Not all browsers implement the same features unfortunately. IE is usually lacking stuff. You can check feature browser support through MDN or caniuse.com

Comment: did you see this in the question: other than doing :document.getElementById('ddlTest').value

Comment: @webdevdani btw why do you have the line : var y = ddlTest && ddlTest.value; ?

Comment: @psj01 That's checking to make sure ddlTest exists and has a value before trying to read a property from it

Comment: @xianshenglu, thank you for pointing that out! I'll update my answer